# Devise after_sign_in_path redirect loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying redirect after signing in, except for some paths.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  if request.fullpath =~ /some_path/
    request.fullpath
  elsif # redirect accordingly
    # ...
  else ...
    ...
  end
end
```

And it's doing a redirect loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you just trying to redirect the user to a different homepage depending on whether he is logged in or not?

Comment: No, I'm trying to *not do redirect* if the user is trying to access a specific url.

Comment: But after signing in the user is always redirected. Do you just want a url that doesn't require a login?

Comment: I'm not following what you are saying. The redirect only happens on sign in, not every http request after, right? So I can just redirect to request.fullpath if it matches a predefined pattern, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.
It has to do with weird and undocumented behavior of the /users/password/edit path, which is only used for unauthenticated password resets.
Using /users/edit solved this problem.

Had to dig through Devise source code to understand this.